# Is there a way to skip the cinematics?

Tags: mass-effect-andromeda

Every time I decide to look at a different planet, new system, etc, I'm forced to sit through a 10-15 second cinematic of the Tempest soaring to the new place. It was nice the first few times, but it's getting a bit tedious to sit through every time I just want to look at stuff, especially if it's just because I accidentally selected the wrong thing.

Is there a way to cancel or skip these cinematics?

Comment: I'm not sure, but isn't that because the game is loading? At least I never tried to skip them because I thought that haha

Comment: Rather than staring at loading screens, they give you something pretty to watch.

Comment: Mass Effect has a history with unskippable loading animations - see http://www.nexusmods.com/masseffect2/mods/2/?

Comment: @Deltharis And don't forget the elevators in the first one.

Comment: @Dragomok I don't feel like that's the same, because elevators often livened the background story with some comments on current galaxy situation and your actions. But yes, that too. And there is also a mod for them - http://www.nexusmods.com/masseffect/mods/69/? - so there is hope for Andromeda.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Updated (04/06/17)**:

A prompt to skip the "autopilot" cutscenes (travelling between planets within a system) was added in [patch 1.05](http://blog.bioware.com/2017/04/04/mass-effect-andromeda-patch-1-05-notes/).

---

*Original Post*:

You can't skip them, and it doesn't even seems to be because the game is loading or anything else.

They just wanted to animate travel between planets, but a lot of [people](http://www.theverge.com/2017/3/24/15047206/mass-effect-andromeda-animations-slow-travel) are complaining about it, so maybe you will have the option to skip them in a future patch.

Comment: Are you sure nothing is being loaded during this time? Granted, I agree... it doesn't seem like anything is loading from my experience as a developer, but I could be mistaken. Just wondering if you have a source for the "They just wanted to animate travel between planets" part of this answer.

Comment: @pushasha I said first in the comments, I was thinking it was hiding some loading screen, but I didn't found any information about it on the net. So I didn't added it.

Comment: @pushasha Can't find it at the moment, but a redditor had a picture they took using Nvidia Ansel, which lets you pause the game at any point and move the camera freely to take picture. During the travel between planets, you can use Ansel to reveal that the ship itself is physically moving to each location, not just a camera moving location. This is easily verifiable by the fact that it takes longer to move to a further away planet than a closer planet. If it was just loading, then you'd expect them to take the same amount of time.

Comment: @SGR Alright then a bit more hope to be able to skip them later :)

Comment: @SGR I was thinking it might be a combination of loading and an animation, but nevertheless, what you said sounds pretty convincing. Thanks!

Comment: @pushasha As I understand it, the loading for a system takes place when you FTL into it and is disguised by the warp images. Once you're in the system, it's all loaded. The models are fairly low poly and are likely just textures stretched over a shape.

Comment: Today's patch notes: "Added option to skip autopilot sequences in the galaxy map". Sounds like we got our answer!